# Boost ASIO - What is async

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

I've been doing a lot of reading, but I just cannot wrap my head around the difference between synchronous and asynchronous calls in Boost ASIO: what they are, how they work, and why to pick one over the other.

My model is a server which accepts connections and appends the new connection to a list. A different thread loops over the list and sends each registered connection data as it becomes available. Each write operation should be safe. It should have a timeout so that it cannot hang, it should not allocate arbitrarily large amounts of memory, or in general cause the main application to crash.

Confusion:
How does `accept_async` differ from regular `accept`? Is a new thread allocated for each connection accepted? From examples I've seen it looks like after a connection is accepted, a request handler is called. This request handler must tell the acceptor to prepare to accept again. Nothing about this seems asynchronous. If the requset handler hangs then the acceptor blocks.

In [the boost mailing list](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2007/04/120339.php) the OP was told to use `async_write` with a timer instead of regular `write`. In this configureation I don't see any asynchronous behaviour or why they would be recommended. From the Boost docs `async_write`  seems more dangerous than `write` because the user must not call `async_write` again before the first one completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous calls return immediately.

That's the important bit.

Now how do you control "the next thing" that happens when the asynchronous operation has completed? You got it, you supply the *completion handler*.

The strength of asynchrony is so you can have an IO operation (or similar) run "in the background" without necessarily incurring any thread switch or synchronization overhead. This way you can handle many asynchronous control flows at the same time, on a single thread.

Indeed asynchronous operations can be more complicated and require more thought (e.g. about lifetime of references used in the completion handler). However, when you need it, you need it.

Comment: The kernel usually manages the operations; in case of IO operations, it could well be parallel in hardware (think IO controller <-> DMA). Even so, multiplexing all events through a select()/poll()/epoll() vastly reduces context switching.

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Asio basic overview from the official site explains it well:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html

The io_service object is what handles the multiple operations.

Calls to io_service.run() should be made carefully (that could explain the "dangerous async_write")